# Please explain the working of * greedy quantifier

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern ptn  = Pattern.compile("a*");
Matcher mtch  = ptn.matcher("bbaac");
if(mtch.find()){
    System.out.println(mtch.group());
}
```

Output - prints nothing

```
Pattern ptn  = Pattern.compile("a+");
Matcher mtch  = ptn.matcher("bbaac");
if(mtch.find()){
    System.out.println(mtch.group());
}
```

Output - aa

I know that it's a very simple problem but still I got confused seeing the behaviour of `*` and `+` (both are greedy quantifier).
Please let me know why in first case output prints nothing i.e `a*` is greedy it should return `aa` as match.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing wrong in your code is that you are not looping over all the found subsequence of the Matcher.

```
while (mtch.find()) { // <-- not if here
    System.out.println(mtch.group());
}
```

The pattern `"a*"` will match two empty Strings before matching `"aa"` in your String, as it is expected because the `*` quantifier allows for zero occurrences. However, the `+` quantifier will not match the empty Strings since it matches one or more occurences ([tutorial about quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)).

```
 b b a a c
^ ^  ^  ^ ^   <-- matches for case of *
```

Comment: Sir Please explain this empty string in bbaac .What I think there should be no empty string in bbaac

Comment: @user3907559 An empty String is a String of length 0. So you won't "see" it but `*` will match it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that there are 5 matches, and you only check for the first one which is an empty string as `a*` can match an empty string (to be more exact, it matches the empty space before the character it cannot match and at the end of string).

Use `while` instead of `if`.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/CZxLlC):

```
String s = "bbaac";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

The number of matches is 5:

- empty string before the first `b`
- empty string before the second `b`
- `aa`
- empty string before the `c` and
- empty (end of) string after `c`.

Using `a+`, with the `+` quantifier meaning *1 or more occurrences*, no empty matches will get extracted and you will only get `aa`.

See the [empty strings on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nT8lB0/1):

[image]

Comment: Please don't mind sir but there is no empty string before first b and between two b's . please explain this

Comment: By saying "empty string" I mean a location before a non-matching character. Just have a look at my demo code, and you will see for yourself.