# C++ regex_search() does not work with star-quantifier

Tags: regex, c++11

I'm compiling this on Linux with g++ 5.4.0

```
string s = "ans42";
smatch result;

if (regex_search(s, result, regex("\\d*")))
    cout << result.str() << endl;
```

Above does match `42` if I change `\\d*` to `\\d+`. But AFAIK both are greedy so both should work! What gives?

Comment: If anyone has the reputation, he can mark the question as duplicate. I found a question that explains what is actually matched in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33808783/4158051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You matched an empty sequence. (in which case `result.position()==0`)

Change to `if (regex_search(s, result, regex("\\d*"), std::regex_constants::match_not_null))`, so at least one character is required for match.

It works for me with gcc 6.1 (`42` is printed)

Comment: Thank you, did not notice that option. This solves the practical aspect of the question. As for the explanation, I found another question that I'll post as comment above.