# Need clarification on regex \w* in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

New to python, not sure if my query feels silly to some one.

If (\w) in regex means, matching any alphanumeric character, and * means  Matching 0 or more occurrences of preceding regex. when we combine them (\w*),
why does it print a list of words instead of characters?

ex:

```
result=re.findall(r'\w','Am newbie in python')
print result
```

Output:

['A', 'm', 'n', 'e', 'w', 'b', 'i', 'e', 'i', 'n', 'p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']

```
result=re.findall(r'\w*','Am newbie in python')
print result
```

Output:

```
['Am', '', 'newbie', '', 'in', '', 'python', '']
```

Comment: You ask to extract **0** or more chars with `*`, it matches empty spaces before any non-matching symbols. Closing with an analogous post for `sed`, it is the same type of issue across all regex engines. **Replace `*` with `+`** if you plan to match non-empty strings. Also, see [this answer, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808692/please-explain-the-working-of-greedy-quantifier/33808783#33808783).

Comment: I don't understand the problem... You seem to have understood well the `*` quantifier ^^

Comment: `*` is a 'grouping' quantifier - with `\w*` you're essentially telling the regex engine: get all unbroken alphanumeric characters - i.e. words.

Comment: * character is greedy. Regex finds the longest strings satisfying your mask.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Is ' ' considered as matching 0 occurrence of preceding regex(\w)

Comment: `\w*` matches  an empty space before a non-matching symbol. A space cannot be matched with `\w` as it is whitespace, not a "word" char. So, the empty space is matched, the space is not.

Comment: oh. so, there is difference between space and an empty space in regex !